# after cancelling alarm manager, setting it again doesn't work(no notification)

Tags: java, android, notifications, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to make my app issue a notification at a specific time(using timePicker) and repeat it daily(using setRepeat method).

Everything is working fine until I cancel the alarm to check if cancellation works or not. But after canceling the alarm if I set the alarm again to issue a notification, it just doesn't work unless my app is running.

I've turned an activity into a dialog and starting with startActivityForResult, getting time setting on the calendar which alarm manager uses. Thanks in advance.

NotificationCenter.class (java file of the activity cum dialog):

```
        // IMPLEMENTATION OF TIME PICKER'S TIME CHANGE EVENT
    timePicker.setOnTimeChangedListener(new TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            savedHour = hourOfDay;
            savedMinute = minute;

        }
    });

    // IMPLEMENTATION OF SAVE BUTTON
    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //using this for couple of reasones
            Boolean isNotification = notificationSwitch.isChecked();
            editor.putBoolean("isNotification", isNotification);
            editor.putInt("saved_hour", savedHour);
            editor.putInt("saved_minute", savedMinute);
            editor.putBoolean("hasTimeSaved", true);
            editor.apply();
            //sending this intent to mainActivity as a result
            Intent result = new Intent();
            result.putExtra("saved_hour", savedHour);
            result.putExtra("saved_minute", savedMinute);
            setResult(2, result);
            finish();
        }
    });
```

MainActivity.xml

```
      @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // To remove status bar
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    // ALARM SERVICE FOR NOTIFICATION
    alarmService = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    alertIntent = new Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, alertIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
// GET THE NOTIFICATION LINEAR LAYOUT AND SET AN ON CLICK LISTENER TO IT
    LinearLayout notificationManager = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.notification_manager);
    notificationManager.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivityForResult(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NotificationCenter.class), 11);
        }
    });
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == 11) {
        Toast.makeText(this,"request_code_ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (resultCode == 2) {
            Toast.makeText(this,"result_code_ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (preferences.getBoolean("isNotification", false)) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "true", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            int savedHour = data.getIntExtra("saved_hour", 0);
            int savedMinute = data.getIntExtra("saved_minute", 0);
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, savedHour);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, savedMinute);
            calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 1);

            Intent alertIntent = new Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, alertIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            alarmService.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, pendingIntent);
        } else {
                alarmService.cancel(pendingIntent);
                Toast.makeText(this,"alarm_cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MyBroadcastReceiver:

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // NOTIFICATION
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setTicker("Alert!")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
                    .setContentTitle("My notification")
                    .setContentText("Hello World!");
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, ChapterOne.class);
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(ChapterOne.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                    0,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    mBuilder.setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_SOUND);
    mBuilder.setPriority(2);
    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify( 0,mBuilder.build());
}
```

}

AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver"  android:enabled="true" android:exported="false"/>
    <service android:name=".NotificationService" android:enabled="true" android:exported="false"/>
```

Comment: Sometimes it happen that the alarm is set correctly but the system don't fire it at the exact time coz of some system policies like batching the alarms. Being said that, to confirm whether an alarm is set successfully(in ur case after canceling it) or not use this adb shell command in your android studio terminal and then using the package name you can confirm whether alarm is set or not> 'adb shell dumpsys alarm >dump.txt' and after that open the file and search it.

Comment: I'll try but never worked with terminal shit before. Thanks anyway.

Comment: well its not what you call it, they are extra tools and you must be accustomed to. Also if you want the system not to delay the delivery of your alarm, try `setExact` instead of `setRepeating`. but they you need to manually reschedule it.

Comment: Set repeating is working just fine.

Comment: Could you provide code for rescheduling the alarm?

Comment: Its simple reschedule if through the pending intent. In your case ChapterOne.class, actually send a custom broadcast from this class and in your manifest add that broadcast in the intent filter of MyBroadcastReceiver. This way when a broadcast is received the alarm will be rescheduled again.

Comment: add this permission: `//--Permission for Broadcast receiver 
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.android.appName"/>` and in your broadcast's intent filter `<action android:name="com.example.android.appName"/>` then call the broadcast from any class as `Intent intent = new Intent();                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
                intent.setAction("com.example.android.appName");
                sendBroadcast(intent);`

Comment: so this will reschedule the alarm? or what?